# Translating the Dutch expression "Ere wie ere toekomt" to French?

Tags: traduction, proverbes

How can you translate Dutch expression *Ere wie ere toekomt* (meaning roughly “credit where due”) in French?

I found this in [Concise dictionary of European proverbs](http://books.google.com/books?id=HJ_BJtntMioC&pg=PA241&lpg=PA241&dq=Ere%20aan%20wie%20de%20ere%20toekomt%20c%C3%A9sar&source=bl&ots=rzczi-o_kH&sig=1sPgN6k1iCCLmENnqCcJhh5udIU&hl=en&ei=nl9OTtvICo6O4gTK5MXmBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&sqi=2&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false):

- *à chacun selon ses œuvres*
- *à chacun selon son dû*
- *à tout seigneur, tout honneur*
- *rendez à César ce qui appartient à César*
- *rendez donc à César ce qui est à César, et à Dieu ce qui est à Dieu*
- *selon les gens l'encens*

Which is better? Is one regularly used? What has Cesar herewith to do?

---

Comment traduire l'expression néerlandaise *Ere wie de ere toekomt* (qui signifie approximativement « honneur à qui honneur revient ») en français?

J'ai trouvé ces équivalents dans le [Concise dictionary of European proverbs](http://books.google.com/books?id=HJ_BJtntMioC&pg=PA241&lpg=PA241&dq=Ere%20aan%20wie%20de%20ere%20toekomt%20c%C3%A9sar&source=bl&ots=rzczi-o_kH&sig=1sPgN6k1iCCLmENnqCcJhh5udIU&hl=en&ei=nl9OTtvICo6O4gTK5MXmBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&sqi=2&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false) :

- *à chacun selon ses œuvres*
- *à chacun selon son dû*
- *à tout seigneur, tout honneur*
- *rendez à César ce qui appartient à César*
- *rendez donc à César ce qui est à César, et à Dieu ce qui est à Dieu*
- *selon les gens l'encens*

Lequel est le meilleur ? Que vient faire César dans cette histoire ?

Comment: Some more fuel for the meta discussions on source language (with here a question in not-too-good English about a translation from another language). Please do discuss on meta: http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/92/may-i-ask-a-question-in-language-est-ce-que-je-peux-poser-une-question-dans-l and http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/1/translation-questions/7#comment-153

Comment: I don't have any issue with this question's topicality.  ;-)

Comment: I Didn't think much people would, but it doesn't hurt to check. (This comment belongs to meta. I slap myself on the head for it.)

Comment: Could you explain what the Dutch proverb means in English or French? Some of your proposals may work, but I don't understand the Dutch text, so I don't know if they are good translations.

Comment: A rough French translation: "Honneur à qui honneur revient". "Credit where due" would porbably be the best in English.

Comment: (Hors sujet : J'adore les questions de traduction Néerlandais->Français posées en anglais! ;-) )

Comment: A similar question: [Comment traduire « what goes around, comes around » ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1616/comment-traduire-what-goes-around-comes-around)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would say that *rendre à César ce qui appartient à César* is the most widely used, before *à tout seigneur tout honneur*. Both are still rather formal.

As for the role of Cesar in this saying, it is a reference to [Mat, XXII, 21](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikisource/en/wiki/Bible_%28King_James%29/Matthew#Chapter_22)