# Comment traduire « what goes around, comes around » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

En anglais, on a l'expression « *what goes around, comes around* », qui veut dire (à peu près) que quoi que la personne fasse, elle devra ensuite faire face aux conséquences de ses actes.

Existe-t-il une telle expression, ou une expression similaire, en français ?

Comment: http://www.linguee.com/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=what+goes+around%2C+comes+around

Comment: Cette phrase est elle utilisé dans un contexte positif?

Comment: @goto Cette expression est assez neutre et peut être utilisée dans un contexte négatif comme positif (la définition 2 du [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what_goes_around_comes_around) le confirme assez explicitement). Point important pour trouver le meilleur équivalent possible, mais [Gille](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/1621/7224) a été assez exhaustif. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Je trouve que l'expression « un prêté pour un rendu » est la plus proche. Elle peut être utilisée aussi bien dans des contextes où « *what goes around, comes around* » concerne une action valorisée que lorsqu'elle concerne une action reprochée.

Lorsque l'expression a une connotation négative ou à la rigueur neutre, je suis les propositions de « on récolte ce que l'on sème » (qui existe en anglais sous la même forme : « *you reap what you sow* ») ou « comme on fait son lit on se couche ». Quant à « qui sème le vent récolte la tempête », elle est similaire, mais sous-entend que les conséquences finales sont pires que la mauvaise action initiale, alors que « on récolte ce que l'on sème » et « comme on fait son lit on se couche » sous-entendent que les conséquences sont à la hauteur de la mauvaise action initiale.

Pour une action positive, on peut dire « un bienfait n'est jamais perdu » ou plus rarement « tout bienfait sera rendu ».

Comment: Au moins dans mon entourage, « un bienfait n'est jamais perdu » se dit aussi pour des actions négatives.

Comment: @Unfrancophone C'est aussi possible pour moi, mais on sent clairement l'antiphrase.

Comment: @Gilles pour moi l'antiphrase est un peu différente: c'est un bienfait ou à tout le moins une action qui se voulait positive, mais qui se retourne au final contre celui qui l'a fait.

Comment: @Benjol Je ne connais pas cette expression. Je peux deviner le sens métaphorique, mais ce n'est pas un idiome pour moi.

Comment: J'ai parfois entendu 'la roue tourne' et supposé que le sens était similaire. Est-ce le cas?

Comment: @Benjol Je ne pense pas. « La roue tourne » signifie que le monde change, et en particulier que ce ne sont pas toujours les mêmes qui ont de la (mal)chance. Il n'y a pas de connotation qu'il y a un gain et une perte liés à un même évènement comme dans « *what goes around comes around* ».

Answer (score 16):

- Comme on fait son lit on se couche.
- On ne récolte que ce qu'on sème.

Il y en a peut-être d'autres....

Comment: Ca n'est pas plutôt "on récolte ce que l'on sème", le proverbe?

Comment: @Nikko :   Le plus souvent rendu sous la forme affirmative dans le contexte de la bible, mais pour ce qui est du proverbe on rencontre indifféremment les deux (les proverbes n'ont pas de forme fixée et dépendent de la tradition). C'est aussi « On ne récolte que ce qu’on sème » qui est donné par [Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/comme-on-fait-son-lit-on-se-couche.php). On trouve souvent aussi l'expression avec un passé composé : « On ne récolte que ce qu'on a semé. »

Answer (score 6):

Le proverbe qui correspond le mieux est

> Qui sème le vent récolte la tempête.

Comment: *Qui sème le vent récolte la tempête* implique que l'action de départ soit mauvaise, et un retour de bâton plus important que la mauvaise action de départ.
*What goes around, comes around* peut s'appliquer à une bonne action et un retour qui peut juste être de même importance.
 
*Qui sème le vent récolte la tempête* −> *those who sow the wind shall reap the whirlwind* qui est, sous diverses formes, très courant en anglais (c'est une citation biblique)

Comment: Merci pour la remarque et la précision, effectivement ma réponse est incomplète.

Answer (score 1):

> ♦ *Cracher en l'air pour que cela vous retombe sur le nez*. Faire une
>   action qui se retourne contre son auteur.
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* - TLFi à « [air](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/air) » ]

Parmi tant d'autres, à l'évidence.

Answer (score 1):

Je penserai plutôt à : ***la roue tourne***.

Comment: Apparaît au [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/roue), « Les choses changent, évoluent. ».

Answer (score 0):

Sinon j'aurais proposé l'expression "le chien qui se mord la queue" qui montre bien quelque chose qui tourne en rond... (assez parlant si vous avez déja eu l'occasion de voir un chien tenter de se mordre la queue ! :) )

Answer (score 0):

L'expression la plus proche en français serait celle qui dit : « Chassez le naturel et il reviendra au galop ».

La traduction littérale de l'anglais est « Plus ça change, plus c'est la même chose ».

Answer (score 0):

ma mère disait toujours :

> ce qui devait arriver... arriva

D'ailleurs :

> ce qui devait arriver advint & ce qui devait arriver est arrivé ; ce
> qui devait arriver… #phraséologie
> Formule fataliste, ne pas échapper à
> qqchose

https://www.languefrancaise.net/Tintin/75348

Answer (score -1):

Pour moi l'expression qui se rapporte le plus est : *le retour de flamme*.

Comment: (N.d.modérateur) Cette réponse a attiré un signalement pour mauvaise qualité. Je ne pense pas qu'elle le mérite au point d'être effacée, mais tout de même, un exemple de phrase serait le bienvenu.

Answer (score -1):

« Tu ne perds rien pour attendre ».

Ainsi la conséquence est sans limite par rapport à la cause initiale (elle insinue même la mort), l'esprit de vengeance et de menace est mieux restitué ainsi que le sentiment de la perte de maîtrise de la situation pour celui qui génère l'action.

Answer (score -1):

Rira bien qui rira le dernier !

Comment: Est-ce que tu pourrais expliquer un peu en quoi le sens est proche de celui de l'expression anglaise ? Je vois un lien, mais par exemple en anglais ça sonne moins comme une promesse de vengeance.

Answer (score -1):

> Qui cherche trouve.

(dans son sens négatif)

Comment: Peux-tu expliquer ?

Comment: Votre réponse est une peu brève.

Answer (score -1):

> Il n'y a pas de tour de chien qui ne revient.

ou

> On récolte ce que l'on sème.

Comment: Ouf, jamais entendu la première, et Google trouve, mais à peine.