# Subjonctif dans les subordonnées

Tags: subjonctif, subordonnées, mode-grammatical

> [Il n'y a pas de tour de chien qui ne revient.](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14014/1514) (proverbe [peu](http://burzee.blogspot.ca/2012/01/ceux-qui-ne-voient-jamais-la-rosee-du.html) [attesté](http://forum.mejliss.com/comment/1056264#comment-1056264))

J'aurais dit « qui ne *revienne* », sans bien savoir pourquoi, peut-être parce que le retour du tour est encore hypothétique au moment de le dire.

Quelle est la raison qui pousse à utiliser le subjonctif ? Et si la raison est valable, pourquoi le proverbe est-il à l'indicatif ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ce proverbe rare semble surtout connu en Belgique. La forme utilisant le subjonctif se rencontre [aussi](http://flic.skynetblogs.be/archive/2005/11/29/bizarre-vous-avez-dit-bizarre.html). Cette dernière est tout à fait acceptable car, d'une part, il ne s'agit pas d'une réalité incontestable; le doute sur le retour du « tour de chien » est possible.

D'autre part, la proposition principale étant à la forme négative, [le subjonctif est privilégié pour la subordonnée](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#83_strong-em-subordonne-relative-indicatif-ou-subjonctif-em-strong), il s'impose même probablement vu la présence d'un « ne » explétif.

Voici quelques proverbes et citations qui montrent que le subjonctif prévaut dans ce style de construction :

- [Il n'est si bon cheval qui ne **devienne** rosse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/rosse).
- [Il n'est pas de problème dont une absence de solution ne **puisse** venir à bout](http://qqcitations.com/citation/181509).
- [Il n'est pas de coiffeur qui ne **puisse** couper ses propres cheveux](http://www.librairiedixdecoeur.com/boutique/achat/produit_details.php?catid=178&id=28381).
- [Il n'est pas de douleur que le sommeil ne **sache** vaincre.](http://qqcitations.com/citation/197432) (Balzac).
- [Il n'est pas de menteur qui ne **taise** le fait qu'il ment.](http://citations.webescence.com/citations/Pascal-Quignard/est-pas-menteur-qui-taise-fait-ment-romancier-est-seul-menteur-qui-tait-pas-4340)
- [Il n'est si belle rose qui ne **devienne** gratte-cul.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gratte-cul)
- [Il n'y a pas de grande tâche difficile qui ne **puisse** être décomposée en petites tâches faciles](http://qqcitations.com/citation/123001).
- [Il n'y a pas de grenouille qui ne *trouve* son crapaud.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grenouille) (*)
- [Il n’est si bonne compagnie qui ne *se sépare* (ou ne *se quitte*).](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/compagnie) (*)
- [Il n'y a pas de mal qui ne **devienne** un bien](http://www.mesexercices.com/recherche_information/proverbes-bretons-il-n-y-a-pas-de-mal-qui-ne-devienne-un-bien_9_85365.htm).

***** Même forme pour l'indicatif et le subjonctif.

A l'exception de celui cité dans la question, je n'ai pas trouvé d'autre proverbe où l'indicatif est indiscutablement utilisé.

> Quelle est la raison qui pousse à utiliser le subjonctif ?

Il s'agit du mode habituel de ce style de construction : proposition principale négative suivie d'une proposition subordonnée comportant un « ne » explétif.

> Et si la raison est valable, pourquoi le proverbe est-il à l'indicatif ?

L'hypothèse d'une rime interne (chien/revient) est plausible.

Comment: [Discussion](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic3636-il-ny-a-pas-que-indicatif-ou-subjonctif-p3.html). J'accepte cette réponse, parce que la négation est bien la clef de la construction (négation qui appelle le subjonctif).

Answer (score 4):

#### Pourquoi l'indicatif

Le propre des proverbes et de vouloir exprimer quelque chose de toujours vrai (même s'il ne s'agit souvent que d'une opinion populaire). D'après [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proverbe) :

> Un **proverbe** est une formule langagière de portée générale contenant une morale, expression de la sagesse populaire ou une vérité d’expérience que l’on juge utile de rappeler.

Concernant le côté hypothétique, parmi les réponses de la question que tu as citée, on trouve aussi « tout bienfait sera rendu », avec un futur qui donne une impression de certitude alors que comme tout futur, il demeure hypothétique.

À ce titre, **[l'indicatif présent](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicatif_pr%C3%A9sent_en_fran%C3%A7ais) est utilisé logiquement, avec la valeur de présent de vérité générale.**

Par ailleurs, la tournure de la phrase combinée à l'indicatif présent [permet une rime](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14023/subjonctif-dans-les-subordonn%C3%A9es/14027#comment26487_14027), mécanisme que l'on retrouve dans plusieurs proverbes (« En avril, ne te découvre pas d'un fil. En mai, fais ce qu'il te plaît. »). J'imagine que celle-ci est utilisée pour faciliter la mémorisation de ces sagesses populaires.

#### Pourquoi le réflexe du subjonctif

Le [subjonctif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjonctif_en_fran%C3%A7ais) est quant à lui utilisé pour exprimer une opinion ou un fait imaginé.

Qu'est-ce qui te pousse à l'utiliser dans ce cas ? Un raccourci de l'éducation que nous avons reçue et qui nous pousse à utiliser le subjonctif derrière un que/qui (j'ai longtemps commis la faute d'utiliser « après que » + subjonctif, y compris pour des faits avérés).

Comment: En plus des emplois justifiés par la grammaire, il y a peut être aussi celui pour la rime?

Comment: @YohannV. J'ai ajouté une note sur ce point.

Comment: Après qu'ils ont lu cette réponse, les intéressés pourront aller lire sur [*après que*](http://www.langue-fr.net/Apres-que-indicatif-ou-subjonctif) ([et là](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11/avant-que-et-apr%C3%A8s-que-indicatif-ou-subjonctif?) sur le site). Pertinent ! +1 pour la fin, je serais curieux de trouver d'autres formules en *que* + indicatif/subjonctif qui mettent en conflit prescriptivistes et descriptivistes.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks J'ai trouvé [cette page](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-25454.php) dont l'esthétique est à apprécier selon les goûts de chacun mais qui a le mérite de fournir plusieurs exemples.

Comment: Attention à l'hypercorrection, il ne faut pas jeter le subjonctif avec l'eau du bain ... ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Ce n'était pas mon propos, mais mes cours de français m'ont laissé la fausse impression qu'il était pratiquement systématique après certaines tournures basées sur « que », alors que le sens a bien plus à voir que la syntaxe grammatical pour déterminer quel mode utiliser.